# Run c++ program using unix terminal

Tags: c++, bash, unix

I have C++ program. there i have used C++ . in order to run that program i'm passing values via unix terminal. But i couldn't run code snippet  by passing args  values.

1. obtain bash build path as

**Users/venushka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testFunctions-blcisknaxkrqribioawblwrttsib/Build/Products/Debug**

2. i executed myFunctions bash as

   `./testFunctions`
3. i pass args as

   `./testFunctions 1`

please find below the code snippet i used

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    //std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    if (*argv[0] == 1) {
        std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
        //test();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when i gives 1 as arg my programe line hello world hasn't executed. what am i do wrong please help me. thank you . please find the image below[image: My terminal image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
if (*argv[0] == 1)
```

argv[0] is a string which is the name of your program.  Dereferencing it (with `*`) gives you the first character.  It will never match `1` which is a non-printing ASCII code.  Instead:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "1") == 0)
```

That will check if the first argument to the program (not its name) is the string "1".

Comment: Can also use `strtol(argv[1])` to compare ints.